# Show a list of recently used tags only from the current locale

Tags: localization, tags

I'm having trouble outputting a list of tags that only includes tags from the current locale.

Here's the setup:

1. I have a site with two locales: english and spanish
2. I have a section with handle newsAndEvents
3. I have a tag field with handle newsTags on entries in that section that is set to translatable to allow my clients to assign locale-specific tags to the entries
4. I have an entry in that section created with a published version for each of my locales. In the english version, I've added a tag "Turtles" to the entry. In the spanish version, I've added a tag "Tortugas" to the entry.
5. On the landing page of my news section, I am displaying a list of recent tags in a sidebar. Here's the code I'm using to do it:

   ```
   {# grab the entries in the specific locale #}
   {% set entries = craft.entries.find({section: 'newsAndEvents', locale: craft.locale}) %}

   {# Grab the related tags for those entries #}
   {% set tags = craft.tags.relatedTo(entries) %}

   {# Build the list #}
   {% if tags | length %}
     <ul class="tag-list">
     {% for tag in tags %}
       <li><a class="tag" href="#">{{ tag.name }}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
     </ul>
   {% endif %}
   ```
6. The problem is, when I'm looking at the english version of my landing page, I get both "Tortugas" and "Turtles" in the list output by the code above. What I want is to only see the tags on english versions entries on the english landing page; and the tags on spanish versions of entries on the spanish landing page.

Some additional info:

- If an entry has only one published version, english for example, any tags I assign to that version do not appear on the spanish landing page, as would be expected.
- On my entry detail pages, I'm using similar code to generate a list of tags assigned to the current entry, and the output is what I expect: english versions only show tags assigned to english versions, not to both english and spanish like on the landing page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brandon at P&T was able to fill in the piece I was missing. He said:

To only get tags that were related from a specific locale, you just need to specify that in your [`relatedTo`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) param:

```
    {% set tags = craft.tags.relatedTo({
      sourceElement: entries,
      sourceLocale: craft.locale
    }) %}
```

With the addition of `order('dateCreated desc').limit(10)` to put some additional constraints on what I was getting back, this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually two problems you have, Adam.

Isn't `dateCreated` – which you are now using with the code you provided – something different to "recently used", your actual plan to filter your tags by? I don't know it there's a built in way to get the therefore necessary info, the "entry-tag-relation creation date".

You could try `dateModified` on the tag model, but I'm not sure if this works (maybe worth a feature request though? → [support@buildwithcraft.com](http://buildwithcraft.com/help) or ["Craft: Feedback and Ideas" section on g+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/106505340287442511226/stream/3ff4ba0f-25e6-4f6f-ad4b-04da3a7e81c9)).

Comment: You're right carlcs: dateCreated is not exactly what I would want. What I really want is "date last used or created, whichever is newer." Thanks for the feature request link. I'll use it.

Comment: Did you try `dateModified desc`? That'd only work if a tag is updated in the DB after each new relation registered on it. Maybe worth a try..

Comment: I thought of that and did try it, but from what I was getting back, it didn't appear that Craft considers applying a tag as a modification.